# Xcode 6 - universal image support

Tags: ios, xcode, image, xcode6, xcasset

I am wondering which image sizes are needed with new XCode 6 and iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus support.

So if I am now having a fullwidth image, which is

```
640 x 80 pixel
```

for an iphone 4s/5 series. So with "@2x". For iPhone 6 plus I need the "@3x" as well. So that would be

```
1242 x 80 pixel
```

?

Update:

My goal is it to have a fullwidth image which looks good on every iphone or ipad (Size class any any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `640 x 80` image is `@2x`, the `@3x` image size would be `960 x 120` (`960 = 640 / 2 * 3`)

Comment: I updated my question. Would that 960 x 120 image fit on every device? @Azat

Comment: No, it don't. I misunderstood your question. iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ sizes are differ. Is it appropriate for you using sliced images? You can specify which areas of image will remain unchanged and which of them will duplicate as pattern: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html

Comment: No, I just want to know which size of image I have to create for iPhone 6 nd 6 plus @Azat

Comment: @davidOhara I updated my comment. It works just like as `UIImage`'s `-resizableImageWithCapInsets:` method

Comment: @davidOhara so for iPhone 6 it will be 750 width and for iPhone 6 Plus 1242

Comment: @davidOhara but you will need to determine the phone model at runtime and use appropriate image, I highly recommend you use more general approach like resizable images

Comment: So in order to support a fullscreen image on iPhone 4s/5/6/6+ I would need 4 sizes, correct?

Comment: No, just 3, because iPhone 4s and 5 have same widths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73594/discussion-between-davidohara-and-azat).